# ubuntu server 14.04 not rendering local characters generated using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-14.04, wicked-pdf, ubuntu-server

I have a pdf page containing Ethiopian characters. It works perfectly in ubuntu desktop 14.04, but when i deploy it to ubuntu server 14.04 the characters are not being displayed.
I am using wicked_pdf gem to generate the pdf page.

I am stuck here for the whole day. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: My guess would be that the server doesn't have the needed font installed.

Comment: Amazing!!! thanks a lot. I installed fonts-sil-abyssinica and it works.

Comment: I made it an answer, feel free to upvote/accept my answer.  Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pdf creators you need to have the fonts you are using to be available on the machine it is doing the creation on.  So in this case the Ethiopian font was installed on the desk top machine, but not on the server, leaving blanks in the PDF.